# Which .NET versions to install on XP?

Tags: .net

I run several XP computers, and just reinstalled one of them. Now, which .NET versions would I need to install on this computer?

On my developing computer I have these versions of the framework:

```
Compact 2.0 SP2
Compact 3.5
2.0 SP2
3.0 SP2
3.5 SP1
```

Do I need to install all these, or does some include the previous ones?

Comment: It depends on what you are developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need to use in your development projects...

You can have just one of them [as pst (once) told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082811/which-net-versions-to-install-on-xp/4082825#4082825) or even all together. I am working with .NET 4.0 but I also have to maintain some other projects that use 2.0 and 3.5...

Comment: Thanks!  My question was really focused in my last sentence, if installing later versions would include previous versions..